# Formatting Number Columns in CellRenderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In aggrid, thousands separator does not work for editable columns. The function 'currencyFormatter' that I use via valueFormatter for other columns performs this operation:

```
function currencyFormatter (params: any) {

    if (params.value === undefined || params.value === null) {

      params.value = 0;

    }

    const operation = new NumberOperations();

    const result = operation.format(params.value);

    return result;

  }
```

But when I call the function in AgGridNumberEditRenderer, it gives the error 'the specified value 2.130,00 cannot be parsed'.

```
function AgGridNumberEditRenderer (params: ICellRendererParams,

    onCheckedChanged: (e: Event) => void) {

    const div = document.createElement("div");

    div.style.textAlign = "center";

    const input: HTMLInputElement = document.createElement("input");

    input.type = "number";

    input.maxLength = 15;

    input.pattern = "^\d*(\.\d{0,8})?$";

    if (params !== undefined && params.data !== undefined && params.colDef !== undefined)

    input.valueAsNumber = params.data[params.colDef.field!];

 

    input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

      input.value = currencyFormatter({value:input.value})

      onCheckedChanged && onCheckedChanged(e);

    });    

   

    div.appendChild(input);

    return div;

  }
```

Column Definition :

```
  {

      colId: "kdvTutar",

      headerName: trans("kdv"),

      field: "kdvTutar",

      valueFormatter: currencyFormatter,

      cellStyle: { "text-align": "right", },

      width: 120,

      cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {

        if (params.data && params.colDef !== undefined) {

          if (params.data.editable !== false) {

            return AgGridNumberEditRenderer(params, (e: Event) => {

              const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

              params.data.kdvTutar = MathOps.round(target.valueAsNumber, 2);

              if (params.data.kayitDurumu === 1) {

                params.data.kayitDurumu = -1;

              }

              target.valueAsNumber = params.data.kdvTutar;

              calculatePinnedBottomRowData();

            });

          }

          return params.value;

        }

      },

 

    },
```